# Como trocar de conta do github?

Tags: git, github

Tenho um conta do git meuemail@gmail.com que esta vinculado as projetos pessoais, no trabalho tenho uma outra conta git meuemail@meutrabalho.com como alternar entre as contas em um mesmo computador ?

Comment: Você utiliza Git Bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando o Git vai assinar um commit ele primeiro procura as informações dentro da pasta .git dentro do projeto e caso não tenha nada definido localmente, ele procura pela configuração global que fica num arquivo chamado .gitconfig na pasta raiz do usuário.

Suponha que eu vá separar meus projetos pessoais e os projetos de uma empresa que chamaremos de Zapt.
Eu costumo ter uma estrutura de pastas da seguinte forma:

```
~/Development
   /github # meus projetos pessoais
   /zapt # projetos da zapt
```

Como é um padrão bem simples, fica fácil de falar para o Git o seguinte:

- Se estiver na pasta github use meu email pessoal
- Se estiver na pasta zapt use o email da empresa

E aí para definir isso, eu crio 2 arquivos:

- .gitconfig-github
- .gitconfig-zapt

E os conteúdos ficam:

```
# .gitconfig-github

[user]
  email = victor@gmail.com
```

E no outro:

```
# .gitconfig-zapt

[user]
  email = victor@zapt.com.br
```

Lembrando que aqui estou mostrando só o email, mas outras configurações como aliases específicos para cada conta e qualquer outra coisa, você consegue separar tranquilamente nesses arquivos.

Mas só fazendo isso, ainda não vai funcionar, nós precisamos informar ao Git quando é parar ler um ou outro, para isso nós editaremos o .gitconfig original para ficar assim:

```
[user]
  name = Victor
[init]
  defaultBranch = main

[includeIf "gitdir:~/Development/github/"]
  path = .gitconfig-github
[includeIf "gitdir:~/Development/zapt/"]
  path = .gitconfig-zapt
```

Note que eu tenho coisas globais ainda, como meu nome e o branch inicial quando criar. Mas utilizo um includeIf exatamente para quando cair numa opção ou outra, ele adicionar meus dados específicos. Só de fazer isso, se eu criar um commit na Zapt, já ficaria com o commit assim:

```
commit e071614f972a15bbf761701a5cf547db961867d (origin/fix/update-map-use-lat-long, fix/update-map-use-lat-long)
Author: Victor <Victor@zapt.com.br>
Date:   Tue Jul 12 12:16:44 2022 -0300

    Fix Map position to use flat lat and long
```

Como podem ver, o email já fica certinho o da empresa e não o meu pessoal.

## Configurando duas chaves SSH

Agora vamos a segunda parte que é ainda mais importante, afinal de contas, se as chaves não estiverem bem configuradas, você não consegue nem fazer push para o repositório.

Primeiro de tudo, você precisa criar chaves SSH separadas, até para facilitar nessa separação, para isso, é só rodar:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "email@pessoal.com" -f "id_rsa_pessoal"
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "email@trabalho.com" -f "id_rsa_trabalho"
```

Ao fazer isso, ele vai criar duas chaves separadas na pasta ~/.ssh, depois basta adicionar na sua máquina usando:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_pessoal
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_trabalho
```

Depois disso precisamos configurar o ssh para também entender quando usar uma chave ou outra. Para isso vamos criar um arquivo config dentro da pasta .ssh:

```
cd ~/.ssh
touch config
code config # você pode usar vi, vim, nano, enfim, editor favorito
```

Lá dentro do arquivo é só editar:

```
# Conta pessoal como default
Host github.com
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_pessoal
   
# Conta do trabalho
Host github.com-trabalho  
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_trabalho
```

Ali está como github, mas para o gitlab é só mudar no Host e Hostname, você inclusive pode ter diferentes configs de diferentes repositórios remotos no mesmo arquivo.

E aí, sempre que for clonar um repositório, se ele for de trabalho, basta editar na url para ficar de acordo com a estrutura acima:

```
git clone git@github.com-trabalho:seu_user/repo_name.git
```

Agora sua máquina está configurada para trabalhar com duas contas do Git.

[Referências e mais informações](https://willianjusten.com.br/configurando-2-contas-de-git-no-mesmo-computador)

Answer (score -3):

Olá se seu sistema operacional for windows você pode apagar ele por meio do credential manager (gerenciador de credenciais).

Passo 1 acesse o credential manager e clique em credenciais do windows:
[image]

Passo 2 localize o github da sua empresa e clique em remover:
[image]

Após isso quando você for efetuar uma alteração ele irá pedir novamente suas credenciais.
Lembrando que não há um modo específico e facilitado para você ter duas contas cadastradas e alterar de uma para outra.

Comment: Desculpa se não fui claro Thales, a pergunta e sobre o protocolo git utilizado para gerenciar código fonte